# Using System.cmd within a Poolboy worker (gen_server) causes silent failure

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I've got a function which is spawned from a poolboy worker

basic overview:

- Phoenix Controller calls Dispatcher with data
- Dispatcher passes data to Poolboy worker
- Poolboy worker spawns a new process with the given data to process
- New process uses the data to call a system command (wget in this instance)

The problem I'm having is when I run the ExUnit test, it gets all the way through to the spawned process fine and I can output the data (using IO.inspect).

When I run the System.cmd("wget".... I see the wget output in the terminal when the ExUnit test runs, so the command is actually being run, but then anything I do after that command doesn't run.

So in my worker if I do this:

```
IO.puts "hello"
System.cmd("wget", opts)
IO.puts "world"
```

Then I see `hello` I see the output from wget but I don't see `world`

If I do something else like:

```
IO.puts "hello"
File.write("/tmp/temp.txt", "test")
IO.puts "world"
```

Then I see both `hello` and `world` and a file is written.

Is there something specific about `System.cmd` that I'm missing that is causing this to be the case? It works fine when it's not run within the separate process, so it's a combination of the process and and System.cmd.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried running a simpler command like `ls`, which you know won't fail? Maybe `wget` fails, not `System.cmd`.

Comment: Also, do you see anything being logged? If you are having a failure, you should see entries in your log.

Comment: What's in "opts"?  Sounds like wget is waiting for some input or something like that and without knowing which opts you're passing it's hard to say for sure what's happening.

Comment: @PatrickOscity - when I run "ls", ["-la"] then it all runs fine but I don't see any of the command output in the terminal. But then if I try and do an IO.inspect on the results of the ls then it stops working again.

Comment: @JoséValim sorry for the stupid question but how do I check the logs when I'm running an ExUnit test? I thought the terminal just outputted the status?

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci - Wget is running as I can see the output from the wget command in the terminal when I'm running the ExUnit test

Comment: @PatrickOscity - update, if I just run "ls", [] then it works and I can see the output when I call IO.inspect on the results of the command

Answer (score 7):

You have entered the part of Elixir marked

*"Here Be Dragons"*

`System.cmd` is just a simple wrapper around `Port` and `Port` is an largely
undocumented wrapper of the Erlang `port` function.

http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#open_port-2

The underlying Erlang BEAM process scheduler is built on the assumption that it 
can "swap" processes at very short time intervals. If you only use Erlang/Exilir
code, it is all engineered to work in the BEAM VM. Any code that can potentially block or hang on a system call needs to be run in a driver. This is a special 
interface into the Erlang VM that isolates the Erlang scheduler from any processes that can hang on system calls.

The Ports driver is setup to deal with calls to external programs.

`System.cmd` ultimately calls

```
 do_cmd Port.open({:spawn_executable, cmd}, opts), initial, fun
```

The Port runs in a separate process and the `do_cmd` routine runs a receive
loop until it receives the exit status from underlying Erlang port. So 
System.cmd will "block" that particular BEAM process until the wget unix 
process exits.

However, the rest of the Elixir BEAM processes will go on their merry way. 
I'm not familiar enough with PoolBoy to know if there is some kind of timeout
monitor or heartbeat on your workers. However, if there is and the wget command
exceeds this timeout, the worker process may exit before the wget command 
completes.

`System.cmd` isn't really setup to deal with all the issues around a command that could potentially take a long time. I'd suggest you look into the `Porcelain` module as a nice wrapper around the rather complex topic of Erlang ports.

https://github.com/alco/porcelain

Or since you are doing a simple wget, using an Elixir or Erlang HTTP client module would likely work much better within the BEAM framework.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, it is very helpful! I tried porcelain but it creates the same issue when using .exec or .shell :( Poolboy does have a timeout but I've set it to :infinity so it should never time out on long running processes. The wget is just an example of 1 shell program I want to run, so whilst something like HTTPoison would solve the file download, I'm then going to be stuck again when I want to call other shell apps (such as imagemagic or openoffice for conversion purposes)

Comment: So to thicken the plot.... The above issue only presents itself if using ExUnit to run the code. If I run it by calling the phoenix route (after running mix phoenix.server) then the code executes and I see all of the expected output...However, doing `results = Porcelain.exec` doesn't save the command output to the `results` variable. The `out` element is just a blank string, whereas I can see the output of the wget in the logger, it's just not saved back to the variable :/

Comment: ExUnit has a timeout for the processes it uses to do async testing. So that is consistant with what you see.

Comment: That makes sense as to why it isn't working in ExUnit although wouldn't setting `async: false` prevent that from being the case? I'm still confused as to why it isn't setting the output of the System.cmd to the variable, even though the command is being called.

Comment: Yet Another Update! Using https://github.com/devinus/sh to execute commands does save the output to the `results` variable (still doesn't work in ExUnit though). So `System.cmd("wget"...` and `Porcelain.exec("wget"...` don't work for this but `Sh.wget` does work

Comment: Interesting, https://github.com/devinus/sh isn't a lot different than System.cmd except for they way it ends. Sh looks for the :eof message before the :exit status. You may have found a bug...

Comment: Can you send me an example of the kind of wget command you are using?

Comment: the command I'm trying to run is `wget --spider -v http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf`  - which I've managed to get working using devinius/sh with `Sh.wget "--spider", "-V", "http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf"` but this still doesn't work in ExUnit

Comment: Okay, that only writes to stderr, not stdout. There are options to merge stderr and stdout, but they might be getting tweeked by ExUnit.`wget --spider -v http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf 2> std.err`
`> more std.err
Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2015-06-21 14:28:11--  http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf
Resolving www.pdf995.com... 98.139.134.174
Connecting to www.pdf995.com|98.139.134.174|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 433994 (424K) [application/pdf]
Remote file exists.`

Comment: I'm pretty sure now that it's not a timeout issue, but an issue of what happens to stderr from the command.

Comment: It also doesn't work just using phoneix.server. But when I use Sh.wget (devinius/sh) that it at least works via the phoenix.server

Comment: Not sure what caused this, but I can repro by just trying to run https://github.com/vjeantet/alerter. It has to be related to error code > 0 and/or writing to stderr :/

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and is able to sidestep it with running wget command with -q option.

```
System.cmd("wget", ["-q", url])
```

This seems to prevent the process from getting stuck, by quietening the output from wget.